# Adobe Scout: gotoAndPlay() function is heavier than it seems?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-scout

[image: profiling the game with Adobe Scout]

At some point of development of my new game, I stumbled upon a problem which lead me to discovery of Adobe Scout. The problem occurred after some time of gameplay when the game started lagging more and more heavily up to the point when the whole application crashed. I did some profiling with Scout, and here's what I found: most, if not every heavy memory load is caused by gotoAndPlay() function (if I understand the data presented by the profiler correctly). This function always seemed and even felt like an easy task for Flash, but turns out it's not? Or is it caused by using text labels instead of frame numbers? I am currently looking for possible workarounds to use this method less, and while I do, it would be infinitely helpful to hear thoughts or possible options from people who are aware of this issue.

Comment: I don't think gotoAndPlay() is your main issue. Imo things that are triggered by that are causing hiccups. Garbage collection is taking a lot of your frame time. Do you create/remove a lot of objects?

Comment: Hm, I removed some of the gotoAndPlays that are called each frame, and it stopped showing up in Scout. But yes, I do create and delete objects a lot, almost all of them are attached to their respective classes, which also have a lot of gotoAndPlays in them.

Comment: That must be the case then. Do you have to do it this way? I'm pretty sure you can achieve same effect in a different way. Also maybe consider using Object Pooling.

Comment: IIRC if your timeline has objects, `gotoAndPlay()` has to construct the frame first, this takes time and can potentially take a lot, if any objects on timeline have code which isn't short enough. Say, parsing a JSON, filtering a bitmap, looping through a million things in a constructor will likely end up as being accounted for `gotoAndPlay()` if an object has to be created as its result.

Comment: gotoAndPlay has barely any effect on memory and CPU indeed but the purpose of that method is a clue by itself. Not only you leave an existing frame with maybe object and listeners not taken care of but you arrive to a frame where more code and more objects are created. Now do that a lot and you got yourself your memory leak.